# _tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!canvas" python code related to tkinter library

Tags: python, tkinter

It seems that there is an error in my Python code related to the Tkinter library. Specifically, the error message indicates that there is an issue with the "move_eggs" function, which is being called by a Tkinter callback. The error message suggests that there is an issue with the "coords" method being called on a canvas object, which could be caused by a variety of factors, such as an incorrect canvas ID, incorrect arguments being passed to the method, or an issue with the Tkinter library itself. but i dont know how to solve that issue

```
from itertools import cycle
from random import randrange
from tkinter import Canvas, Tk , messagebox, font

canvas_width = 800
canvas_height = 400

root = Tk()
root.title("Engg Catcher")
c = Canvas(root, width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height, background="sky blue")
c.create_rectangle(-5, canvas_height-100, canvas_width+5, canvas_height+5, fill="light green", width=0)
c.pack()

color_cycle = cycle(["blue", "green", "pink", "yellow", "cyan"])
egg_width = 25
egg_height = 55
egg_score = 10
egg_speed = 500
egg_interval = 4000
difficulty = 0.95
catcher_color = "black"
catcher_width = 100
catcher_height = 100
catcher_startx = canvas_width / 2 - catcher_width / 2
catcher_starty = canvas_height - catcher_height - 20
catcher_startx2 = catcher_startx + catcher_width
catcher_starty2 = catcher_starty + catcher_height
catcher = c.create_arc(catcher_startx, catcher_starty, catcher_startx2, catcher_starty2, start = 200, extent= 140, style="arc", outline=catcher_color, width = 3)
game_font = font.nametofont("TkFixedFont")
game_font.config(size = 18)

score = 0
score_text = c.create_text(10, 10, anchor="nw", font = game_font, fill="darkblue", text ="Score: " +str(score))

lives_remaining = 3
lives_text = c.create_text(canvas_width - 10, 10, anchor="ne", font = game_font, fill="darkblue", text ="Lives: " +str(lives_remaining))

eggs = []

def create_egg():
    x = randrange(10, 740)
    y = 40
    new_egg = c.create_oval(x, y, x+egg_width, y+egg_height, fill=next(color_cycle), width = 0 )
    eggs.append(new_egg)
    root.after(egg_interval, create_egg)

def move_eggs():
    for egg in eggs:
        (eggx, eggy, eggz2, eggy2) = c.coords(egg)
        c.move(egg, 0, 10)
        if eggy2 > canvas_height:
            egg_dropped(egg)
    root.after(egg_speed, move_eggs)

def egg_dropped(egg):
    eggs.remove(egg)
    c.delete(egg)
    lose_a_life()
    if lives_remaining == 0:
        messagebox.showinfo("Game Over!" , "Final Score: " + str(score))
        root.destroy()

def lose_a_life():
    global lives_remaining
    lives_remaining -= 1
    c.itemconfigure(lives_text, text = "Lives: " + str(lives_remaining))

def check_catch():
    (catcherx, catchery, catcherx2, catchery2) = c.coords(catcher)
    for egg in eggs:
        (eggx, eggy, eggx2, eggy2) = c.coords(egg)
        if catcherx < eggx and eggx2 < catcherx2 and catchery2 - eggy2 < 40:
            eggs.remove(egg)
            c.delete(egg)
            increase_score(egg_score)
    root.after(100, check_catch)

def increase_score(points):
    global score , egg_speed, egg_interval
    score += points
    egg_speed = int(egg_speed* difficulty)
    egg_interval = int(egg_interval* difficulty)
    c.itemconfigure(score_text, text = "Score: " + str(score))

def move_left(event):
    (x1, y1, x2, y2) = c.coords(catcher)
    if x1 > 0:
        c.move(catcher, -20, 0)

def move_right(event):
    (x1, y1, x2, y2) = c.coords(catcher)
    if x2 < canvas_width:
        c.move(catcher, 20, 0)

c.bind("<Left>", move_left)
c.bind("<Right>", move_right)
c.focus_set()
root.after(1000, create_egg)
root.after(1000, move_eggs)
root.after(1000, check_catch)
root.mainloop()
```

the game run as i expected but there is error

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\windows10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\windows10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 861, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "D:\Documents\SEM4 SAD1\DFP40203(PYTHON)- MADAM FATIMAH\ASSSIGMENTS\project\project.py", line 49, in move_eggs
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\windows10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2822, in coords
    self.tk.call((self._w, 'coords') + args))]
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!canvas"
```

Comment: This usually means you're trying to call a canvas method after the canvas has been destroyed.

Comment: `check_catch` probably is executed after `root.destroy` has been called. Can happen to your other *self calling* function via `after` that you have implemented as well.

Comment: Call the ```root.quit()``` instead of the ```root.destroy()```.